# SQL changing the id when running a join statement in VS Studio

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently started to work with SQL in the Visual Studio environment, I have created the following two tables and populated them with values, these are the command for the creation of the tables users and photos:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE TABLE photos(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
image_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

Now these are the statements that I ran to populate the tables

```
INSERT INTO users(username) Values
('Colton'),('Ruben');


INSERT INTO photos(image_url,user_id) VALUES
('/alskjd76',1),
('/lkajsd98',2);
```

Now if I run the statement

```
SELECT *
FROM photos
JOIN users;
```

I get the tables:
[image]

Now if I run the command:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN photos;
```

I get the table

[image]

Here are the tables of users and the tables for photos.
[image]

[image]

Now my question is why is it that "id" column in the second table is changed to 4,4,5,5 when the actual "id" column of the users table only contains the values 1,2? The first instance seems to respect this why doesn't the second?

EDIT: It seems to be displaying the following now when running the commands

```
SELECT *
FROM photos
JOIN users;
```

[image]

and when I run :

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN photos;
```

[image]

Edit: this seems to be correct now, is this right, it seems to have been solved with the deletion and recreation of the tables entirely. I think that V.S studio might have mistakenly taken the table to have more present photos with id's 1-3.

Comment: Please include images of "select * from photos" and "select * from users" independently.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the inconsistent behaviour you described. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tMzgfSEnVD2BxJRLPWbudL/0

Comment: @ggordon I have included the tables

Comment: @Shadow it seems to be providing 1's and 2's now, weird.

Comment: @lambdaepsilon then you should delete this question.

Comment: I still have a question @Shadow as seen in my edit. I don't want to flood, with another question when I can just ask here.

Comment: It's the other way around: if you have a new question, ask a new question, don't edit it into an existing one! All previous comments and answers are invalidated this way.

Comment: further @Shadow while the issue resolved itself I think that the occurrence of such an error can still be of use to someone. I concur with posting a new question but not on deleting the present one.

Comment: I completely disagree with your conclusion. 1) what would you search for to find this question? 2) vs code does not interpret sql code. It passed the code to mysql, which executed it. You probably messed up something (like deleted the records, but did not drop and recreate the table). There is simply no error here, nothing to answer.